# Is there a way to turn off the warning for drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I turn off warnings in drupal 7?

Comment: Please be more specific. What warnings are you trying to turn off? Are you sure they are Drupal warnings, or are they PHP warnings?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fix it? Usually warnings are a sign of bugs.

Comment: Sometimes a warning causes the page to flush out, triggering other issues which prevent you diagnosing the original warning.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am assuming you mean the messages at the top of the page, but you did not provide any detailed information.

In Drupal 7, navigate to `admin/config/development/logging` and choose the radio button "None" as seen below:
[image: Logging and Errors]

Answer (score 1):

Other than using the GUI at `admin/config/development/logging`, there are two other methods to change the **Logging and errors** option. These lend themselves to scripting and automation.

- Using Drush CLI, we can do: `drush vset error_level 0`
  Use `drush vset error_level 1` to select **Errors and Warnings**, or,
  `drush vset error_level 2` to select **All**.
- If you do not have Drush installed, this option can be toggled in `settings.php` by adding `$conf['error_level'] = 0;` to the file. For options other than turning the logging and error display off, the codes are the same as those I list above for the Drush method.

Comment: +1 useful answer thank you for D7. To add some more info, from myself trying this: `drush vset error_level 0` turns of all errors. The answer doesn't say which number `0`, `1`, `2` does what. So presumably, as I found, if `0` turns off everything then `1` enables just Errors and Warnings and `2` enables everything. Also I had to clear cache `drush cc all`